# MVC and Swing in desktop application

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller, design-patterns

After realizing that I have completely ignored the MVC pattern I have tried to utilize the concept in an application with a Swing view. I have now read most of the posts on the subject of MVC with Swing but am still a bit confused, because it is too complicated for me to grasp, and I think I need some basic clarifications so I don't set off on the wrong path.

I also wonder how common it is to use MVC in real projects. Many online tutorials seem to leave out the controller and mix it with the model, while I was confused by XSTL:s business logic capabilities. Why would you want to address a datasource from a JSP view?

These thoughts aside, my proper question is this:

If you have a Swing component, should event listener in that Swing class update the component state through calling (static perhaps?) methods in a POJO controller class, which in turn gets the appropriate business logic from the model, which is made up by POJO class hierarchy and associated persistence?

Comment: Welcome to a hornets nest.  Swing does mix the MVC paradigm allowing the "VC" to be virtualised into a single component.  Good or bad is irrelevant, that's just how it is.  What it does do is try and separate the data from the view. There are some schools of thought that state you should remove the "control" element out of the view into it's own class, personally I think this just increases the complexity and invites more problems then it's worth - IMHO.  Generally speaking, your view/controller should never be able to directly change the data, that's the responsibility of the model - IMHO

Comment: Ah, thank you. This made things a bit more clear. But, would you agree that it makes sense to introduce a separate controller if the GUI implementation is likely to change (to SWT for example)?

Too bad I can't upvote your comment -- don't have the reputation yet :)

Comment: A separate controller will only make sense if the API/frameworks work in a similar fashion, have the some type of interfaces.  That said, if you write your controller using the same paradigim as the models have been written in (ie start with an interface, move to an abstract implementation and then allow multiple concrete implementations), it would feasible.  It would need to be a considered balancing act, but seen as I like to abstract everything so that the implementation is not know to those using it, yes, I would consider it a reasonable idea

Comment: Brilliant! For major GUI implementation changes, my preliminary conclusion is that studying the event listener method bodies (hopefully well documented!) would provide pretty much the same value as moving this functionality to a separate controller, even though the controller could be slimmer and hence easier to read perhaps.

I think your comments have saved me hours of doubt! Thank you ever so much!

Comment: thanks for the tip. will do!

Comment: Read this excellent article where the author builds a real Swing GUI using MVC principles: http://java-articles.info/articles/?p=196

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've worked as a freelance for a long time and almost 90% of the projects were about Java Swing (Desktop applications). Also a lot of projects involved migration from languages like Visual Fox Pro to Java, it was a pain, because the hard part is not think in the logic which is already done, the hard part is take the code that is a mess and turn it into a good-looking code following the good practices and using design patterns, that's why it is a good idea to make a schema or a map in your mind how you can separate your code following the concepts of Model, View, Controller.

MVC as mentioned helps you to have a good-looking, maintainable and easy to read code, as well as you follow the programming paradigms and good practices.

View: Obviously, the part that interacts with the user (user interface), in case of Swing, your windows, frames, panels and all the code that involves the graphic components you need for your app.

Controller: Involves the core or business logic you stablish for your application, in this "layer" you should include the functionality and the "how my application will achieve the goals?".

Model: Related with the data you manage, for example, your entities and classes that represents the data you want to manage or give maintenance.

Applying MVC is not so hard, but as I mentioned, it could be sometimes a pain when you have to migrate your code from a not-applying-MVC structure to a MVC structured application. It is easier to start coding using MVC.

A way I get used to it is by using maven and separate my application into little "modules", of course, you don't need maven, I just found it useful in that moment, but in any case you can try practicing or get used to MVC by separating your application into little projects, for instance:

Java Project 1: application-data-model (contains all the code related with data management: entities, dtos, beans, daos)

Java Project 2: application-core-controller (contains all the business logic and functionality, you can use a facade pattern here if you want to make your code more "transparent" when you relate with your view)

Java Project 3: application-view-ui (contains all the panels, frames and graphic components)

Working this way helped me (and forced me) to get used to separate my code and keep an eye on what really matters to the project I'm working on. For instance, if I'm on application-data-model I'm focused in data model, I'm not thinking in business logic nor graphic interface.

Long explanation, maybe somebody could do it better, but hope I could have helped you or at least gave you a hand with this.

Best regards.

Comment: Thank you! I will need some time to think this through before I consider making it the accepted answer though. It seems logical to have business logic in the controller, but my understanding was that this was not a good idea and that it should be part of the model.

Comment: don't worry, we're here to help. You mentioned a good point, and I agree with you that model should contain some logic, but that logic should just concern to the data access and entities you handle like DAOS. In Controller you can have other processes like salary calculation, responsibility delegation. And, again as you wrote, controller will use model to manage or map the data. You can add additional patterns like facade (as I mentioned) to separate a bit more your business logic from your view.

Comment: @MarceloTataje: So when I compare this to typical Java Web app,Controller will be mapped to Service Layer, Model to DAO layer and View to Web layer correct? I ask this as I will be converting my Web app project to Java desktop application.

Comment: @MarceloTataje : Also Can I use Spring for dependency injecting my controllers with Models and Views with controllers and Hibernate with Data Persistence? this seems to be straightforward as long as i maintain single instance of controller(Service) and model(DAO) as I do in my web application. Also these need to be stateless correct?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer and yes, you can make that comparation. In my opinion Spring is one of the best frameworks I've worked with. I really recommend, even when you are not in a Web environment and turning it into a desktop, you can apply the concepts you mention in your comments, Spring will make a good job in simplifying many of the functionality you want to achieve during migration. All depends on you my friend, you can achieve the functionality using standard components or get help from a framework like Spring which suits very good in this case.

Answer (score 3):

Firs the URL for basic understanding of MVC

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller

Now the approach to implement it in Swing applications. Don't get confused with controller functionality with the listeners functionality.

1. UI controls and listeners attached to them should be defined in your view classes.
2. On any event, whenever you need to invoke a business logic, then you need to call the controller class. Like fetching some value from the database.
3. Controller class should talk to your model to fetch the data and manipulate it if required.
4. Model classes should work on the data.

The idea of using MVC is to reduce redundant code and more manageable code. So if you are doing some calculations/manipulations then those can be moved to Controllers. Controllers can be called from different views requiring the same stuff. Similarly model can be used by multiple controllers to fetch the data.

Comment: I suspect this is what is called thick controller. I've seen some comments saying that the controller should be as thin as possible, so I'm thinking everything that could be handled in the model should be handled there. Perhaps I'm still in that confused state but will read a bit more before before I accept/upvote your answer.

Comment: So would you say the following line of thinking is wrong:

"We quickly discovered that this split didn't work well in practical terms because the view and controller parts of a component required a tight coupling (for example, it was very difficult to write a generic controller that didn't know specifics about the view). So we collapsed these two entities into a single UI (user-interface) object," (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/architecture-142923.html)

Comment: I agree that it id hard to achieve the pure MVC model. It is mainly because the it works on listeners model. But I still believe that a lot of code can be moved to controllers if not all. In short if you love MVC, you should be able to comply to it as close as possible :-)